# AngularJS directive to double element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have this in my HTML:

```
<div my-doubling-directive>
   ... Lots of children here ...
</div>
```

After my directive runs I want

```
... Lots of children here ...
... Lots of children here ...
```

so it's basically doubling the output, but not leaving the div that the directive is on.  I'm thinking I need some type of transclude on the link method, but I'm stuck.  I've seen another example of doing this via a filter, but I'm using this as a learning example now for custom directives.

Comment: using directive transclusion is probably the easiest way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-transclude` twice.

```
app.directive("myDoublingDirective", function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div><div ng-transclude></div>",
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/agtGt/1/

Comment: I needed to take this to the next step and make it dynamic how many times, so I ended up with this.  Was the only way I could find to make the template dynamic.  .directive('elementRepeat', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var html = element.html();
            element.empty();

            for (var i = parseInt(attrs.elementRepeat, 10) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                element.append(html);
            }
        }
    };

Comment: @Scott could you use `ng-repeat` with `ng-transclude`?

Comment: I was trying to do something like that, but I have an integer at this point representing the number of repetitions I need, and I couldn't figure out the syntax to make it work that way.